# How to create a modal in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

Hi I am unable to create a modal in AngularJS, also, I don't know where to start regarding modal creation implementation in angularJS. Please share your suggestions or any tutorials on how to create a modal in AngularJS. Thank you!

Comment: consider starting with [angular-ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

Comment: @PankajParkar I've seen this already but don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is something you could do yourself. However, there are plenty of libraries that already do this.

https://pathgather.github.io/popeye/

If you want to pursue yourself then checkout Ben's article on the topic.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2806-creating-a-simple-modal-system-in-angularjs.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an custom modal or dialog box you first need to create a directive and need to control the behaviour of the popup based on an event add a handler that will open the dialog box such as

```
//Keep this event at the top of your hierarchy.
$scope.$on('OPEN_DIALOG_BOX',function(event,data){
    event.stopPropagation();//stops the event from bubbling up the event chain.
    //add a variable that will show or hide the modal dialog box.
    $scope.hideDialog = true;
    //use data to pass custom message to bind in your html.
    $scope.message = data.message; 
});

//Call this event
$scope.$emit('OPEN_DIALOG_BOX');
```

or

You can use angular material [dialog box](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog).

Or

Use ng-dialog as explained in [this blog](http://archugs.blogspot.ae/2014/12/angularjs-ngDialog.html)

[FIDDLE FOR THE CODE SNIPPET](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/10299/)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You, I've a small problem in running, I don't know what dependant links are required to run a modal dialog in AngularJS. Like there are some CDNs that are required, please let me know what are the required links or CDNs.

Comment: Sorry i am not able to get you, Are you asking which version of angular you have to use for so you can use angular [1.5](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js), thanks and if helps please accept the answer so that it could be helpful for others.

Comment: Will you please run the code in snippet or provide any demo link... I'm not able to run your code. Thank you!

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/10299/) i hope this helps.